# Trying to use two middle ware passing them as array

Tags: middleware

app.use([logger,authorize])

Error:
TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You usually don't pass them as an array. You pass them as a comma seperated list as denoted by https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.METHOD.

This would then be

```js
app.use(logger,authorize)
```

However if you would like to call them as an array, take a look at [function.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)